# Tab key is not registered as keydown in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, dom-events, keydown

I am creating a form with multiple input fields, I am trying to call a function on the press of <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key when an input is in focus. I am using the following code:

> ```
> name_input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
>
>         alert("Except Tab"); //This runs on press of any key except tab.
>
>         if((e.key=="Enter")||(e.keyCode==9)){  //This if works fine on desktop but not in mobile.
>             e.preventDefault();
>             if(name_input.value.length!=0){
>                 hide(".js-reply-1", 2);
>                 document.querySelector(".c-dialogue.name").innerHTML = "Hello, " + name_input.value;
>                 alert("hello"); //This doesn't run on the press of "Tab" in mobile.
>                 intro_tl.resume();
>             } 
>         }
>     });
> ```

Everything is working as expected in desktop, but in mobile the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press goes completely undetected by event listener and the code inside it doesn't run. I am also attaching a picture of the button just in case if I am referring to the wrong key as "Tab" key.

[image]

I tried searching everywhere and couldn't find anything of help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a specific answer to my own question, but one work around could be to set visibility:hidden to all the other input fields, this will always bring enter button in the keyboard, I thought I should share it in case someone's trying to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for refreshing an old topic, but maybe someone will find this knowledge useful.

I had a similar issue and you need to know that this problem is not related to a browser bug or fault in your code. There is no possible to handle keydown's `event.key` or `event.keyCode` on Android. The reason is the Android "virtual" (or sometimes called "soft") keyboard (Gboard) which doesn't provide information about pressed keys so we cannot read them via JS code run in a web browser.

If you need more information check [the official bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639).

As an alternative, you can try to use a physical keyboard or install some other Android virtual keyboard, but I'm aware that this is not a solution to the problem, because we can't require this from end users of our applications.